# Can I select all cells from all worksheets in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, keyboard-shortcuts, vba

I want to select every cell in an Excel workbook from all sheets at the same time. Is there any keyboard shortcut or VBA code to manage this?

Comment: Short answer: no. Longer: why do you need to do so?

Comment: I need a macro that deletes all formulas in a whole workbook and replaces the formulas with the values they put out. I thought about selecting all cells, copying them and pasting them in a special way. I can already do this with one sheet at a time but I need this for all sheets in a workbook

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click on the left-most tab (i.e., the tab for the first sheet). 
<kbd>Shift</kbd>+click on the right-most tab. 
You have now selected all sheets.

Finally, click on the triangle to the left of the `A` column header,
above the `1` row label, and below the name box. 
You have now selected all cells on all sheets.

Answer (score 0):

I have found my solution.

I [looped](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/142126/macro-to-loop-through-all-worksheets-in-a-workbook) through all worksheets and put inside the loop some code that selects every cell in a sheet.